# Redirect "specific" traffic to another pc on the network for vpn

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, vpn, redirection

I have two computers on my network:

- Computer A - main pc (Windows 8 Pro)
- Computer B - pc with VPN (VPNINIUM) installed (Windows 7 Home Premium)

What I wish to do is dynamically route certain IP address via the PC with the VPN for instance:

- If I visit http://google.co.uk (192.0.0.0), I wish for it to not go
  trough the VPN
- But if I visit http://redirect.co.uk (192.0.0.1), I wish for this
  to be redirected to the PC with the VPN so that the connection is
  masked.

Is there any software that can do this?

Comment: You could probably do this by editing the routing table.

Comment: can you explain?